# attempting to reassign std::function with std::bind and getting error "attempting to reference a deleted function"

Tags: c++, xcode, visual-studio, std-function, stdbind

I'm trying to use function pointers to a class member function and then use std::bind to call that function on an object of that class in a separate function. Within this separate function, I can bind the object and function pointer once, and then a second time in Xcode, but not with MSVS2015...

Here is some basic code that reproduces the issue I'm having. Everything compiles and runs fine on Xcode:

```
class AClass
{
public:
    bool isNumber1()
    {
        return num == 1 ? true : false;
    }

private:
    int num;
};

typedef bool (AClass::*isFunction)();

bool checkIsFunc (AClass& object, isFunction function)
{
    auto f = std::bind(function, object);

    f = std::bind(function, object); // Error occurs here

    return f();
}

int main (int argc, char* argv[])
{

    AClass obj;

    bool outcome = checkIsFunc(obj, &AClass::isNumber1);

    return 0;
}
```

However, with MSVS2015, I get the following error:

```
error C2280: 'std::_Bind<true,bool,std::_Pmf_wrap<bool (__thiscall AClass::* )(void),bool,AClass,>,AClass &> &std::_Bind<true,bool,std::_Pmf_wrap<bool (__thiscall AClass::* )(void),bool,AClass,>,AClass &>::operator =(const std::_Bind<true,bool,std::_Pmf_wrap<bool (__thiscall AClass::* )(void),bool,AClass,>,AClass &> &)': attempting to reference a deleted function
```

Any ideas what I am doing wrong here or why this works in Xcode but not VS?

Thanks!

Jim

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::bind` does not return a `std::function` object but one of an implementation-defined binder type. Here, then:

```
auto f = std::bind(function, object);
```

`f` is deduced to be this binder type, and this binder type doesn't have to be assignable, only CopyConstructible and MoveConstructible. Quoth the standard, [func.bind.bind]/5:

> *Remarks:* The return type [of std::bind] shall satifsy the requirements of `MoveConstructible`. If all of `FD` and `TiD` satisfy the requirements of `CopyConstructible`, then the return type shall satisfy the requirements of `CopyConstructible`.

`FD` and `TiD` are the bound function type and the argument types, respectively. Note that it says nothing about `MoveAssignable` and `CopyAssignable`, which means<sup>1</sup> that the binder isn't required to satisfy them. And that means that the assignment

```
f = std::bind(function, object); // Error occurs here
```

is not required by the standard to work.

It appears that MSVC's implementation of `std::bind` sticks to this, while libc++ (which I believe comes with Xcode, but I don't develop for Mac OS X) is more lenient.

If you want `f` to be a `std::function`, you have to declare it as one explicitly:

```
std::function<bool()> f = std::bind(function, object);
```

And then the reassignment will work as well because `std::function` is assignable.

<sup>1</sup> along with the fact that such a requirement is not mentioned anywhere else

Comment: Ahh, I was starting to come to this conclusion. I was trying to figure out what bind returned and then thinking to make that a pointer, to which I updated later in the execution. As soon as I was creating a std::function, you responded! Thanks again!